# Xamarin error: Pkcs does not exist in System.Security.Cryptography on Android

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin

I'm getting Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Pkcs' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography' (are you missing an assembly reference?) when compiling for Android.

The code is shared library which is referenced in Android and Mono targets.
Android's target framework is 4.4 (tried 5.0 to no avail). Mono is .NET 4.5.

Android's version references Mono.Android and Mono.Security (2.0.5.0), Mono version - System.Security 4.0.0.0.

If I add a conditional compilation directive to turn off Android and leave just Mono, it builds.

http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aSystem.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms states that Android supports this. Xamarin, however, does not offer me System.Security.dll and instead there is Mono.Security in case of Android.

How can I get System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs under Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that System.Security.dll is not supported for Xamarin.Android (nor Xamarin.iOS). It's probably a mistake that the docs exist for Xamarin.Android.

I've been maintaining a (slight) fork of the Bouncy Castle cryptography library for use with Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS here: https://github.com/jstedfast/bc-csharp - you'll want to check out the vs2010 branch (my changes are not made on the master branch).

In the vs2010 branch, you'll find a BouncyCastle.Android.csproj and a BouncyCastle.iOS.csproj that you can use when targeting one of the Xamarin platforms.

I'm not sure what you are using SignedCms for, but since it's often used for S/MIME, you might be interested in my S/MIME library which works on Xamarin platforms called [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) using the aforementioned BouncyCastle fork. Even if that's not what you need it for, you may still want to check it out for examples of how to use BouncyCastle's crypto to do the equivalent of SignedCms stuff. Check out [SecureMimeContext](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/MimeKit/Cryptography/SecureMimeContext.cs) and [DefaultSecureMimeContext](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/MimeKit/Cryptography/DefaultSecureMimeContext.cs) for examples (specifically the Sign() and EncapsulatedSign() methods). The [WindowsSecureMimeContext](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/MimeKit/Cryptography/WindowsSecureMimeContext.cs) code uses the System.Security.dll SignedCms APIs in the EncapsulatedSign() and Sign() methods.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm indeed about to do S/MIME. Your answer helps, will check your library now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The System.Security.* code is being improved in Mono right now and in consequence it will eventually be available on Xamarin platforms as well. Specifically the Pkcs classes were taken from .NET Core managed implementation and they are likely to ship with Mono 5.18. If you want something right now, then [BouncyCastle](https://github.com/jstedfast/bc-csharp) and the aforementioned [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) is probably your only option.

Comment: We hit the exact same issue but decided to fix it in Mono instead of using workarounds or 3rd-party libraries. The code is already present in Mono GIT repository and available for anyone to try (subject to the gruesome build process).